# Navigation or Progress Bar Circle For Website

Tags: html

Im trying to build a website using progress indicator - every time a page is complete it will go on to the next page and the circle would fill in and the next step or page would show up - if somebody can point me to the right tutorial site or help me out I would appreciate it. Don't know if its called PRORGRESS BAR, either. thanks!

Link to what im trying to explain thanks.
http://ochodos.com/example.png

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/progress-bars-tutorial.php

this bootstrap progress-bar is what I use and this seems a nice tut.